# Strapi - Multiple media field not showing in API

Tags: strapi

I'm creating a portfolio with Strapi as backend. I have "project" collection type including :

- slug (UID)
- title (Text)
- description (Rich text)
- thumbnail (single media)
- gallery (multiple media)
- categories (relation with another collection: "category")

When I open my API http://localhost:1337/api/projects?populate=* here is what I got :

```json
{
    "data": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "attributes": {
                "slug": "title",
                "title": "Title",
                "description": "Text",
                "createdAt": "2022-06-13T15:58:12.851Z",
                "updatedAt": "2022-06-15T10:52:08.092Z",
                "publishedAt": "2022-06-13T15:58:16.392Z",
                "thumbnail": {
                    "data": {
                        "id": 1,
                        "attributes": { ... },
                        }
                    }
                },
                "categories": {
                    "data": [
                        {
                            "id": 1,
                            "attributes": { ... }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

As you may notice, every field is showing well except of my **gallery** one (multiple media).
Can someone help me finding this object?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

if you want to deeply populate these fields, you have to write out what you want to be populated. Just adding the '*' won't work here. There are community solutions that work with just the '*', but they don't work reliably for me.

But you can try them out anyways if you want to: https://market.strapi.io/plugins/strapi-plugin-populate-deep

Comment: Indeed, this plugin didn't work for me neither... The only solution that I've found is to set the "gallery" field as required on Strapi BO.